# Ctrl + C not working in flash player(swf file) when browser is Google Chrome

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have my project developed in Flex3,

> `<<Site Link Removed now>>`

You can check it here, the problem I'm facing is, copying(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>) the content from screen `textarea` when the `swf` is running in chrome browser.

suppose, I have to add some text on the stage, so the text area which is opened on the left side, I can't copy the text written in text area, although by right clicking in `textarea`, and selecting the copy option, thats working, but my client has asked for copying the content by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, although it's working very fine with other browsers,

only chrome is not supporting copying(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>), although selecting all(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> ) is working

So this the thing, which I thought I should discuss, may b someone also hav same problem,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` to detect "C" being pressed.  Then check for `ctrlKey` to see if it is down, and use `System.setClipboard(source.text);` to set the clipboard content.

```
textArea.addEventListener (KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

private function onKeyDown ( ev : KeyboardEvent ) : void 
{
    if (ev.keyCode != 67 || !ev.ctrlKey) return;
    var text:String = textArea.text;
    System.setClipboard( text);
}
```

Beware, though: Sometimes odd things can happen simultaneously, like the text content disappearing and such.  You might have to work around that!

Comment: Thanx man for this awesome code, but it was not running on KEY_DOWN event, then i used KEY_UP, it worked, i dowloaded latest chrome browser,

Comment: The keyboard stuff has a tendency to do weird things - I tested it on my own computer, and it worked fine ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not just chrome that does this, safari and some other browsers do it too.

Your best bet is to use a JavaScript library to catch these keyboard events and then pass them through to your Flex app.

For communicating between the two: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

How to detect keyboard short cuts in JavaScript (have tested Ctrl+1 in Chrome on Windows XP: http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/

Comment: It may also be that you are using KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN rather than KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP in your listener. The former hasn't detected a press of a ctrl/shirt/alt key for me in the past. (Sorry if this is obvious in your example, however I am unable to look at it currently)

Comment: I checked it on Safari, Mozilla, IE, it's working fine, i couldn't find whts the problem thr in chrome, n e ways, thanx @robmcm for this

Comment: FF3 with FP 10,1,82,76 is fine;
Chrome with FP 10,1,82,76 doesn't work;
Safari 5 with FP 10,1,82,76 is fine