# In Latest Flash Player Ctrl + C & Ctrl + V not working in Chrome When Caps lock on?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, apache-flex, keyboard, copy-paste

Its happen only in latest version of flash player (version 23).Ctrl + C & Ctrl + V not working in Chrome When Caps lock on. Its happening in Flex based web application.  But same working fine in IE. How to solve this?

Comment: Which flex version are you using? I just tried this on a AS3 flex website on Chrome and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ctrl + C not working in flash player(swf file) when browser is Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665497/ctrl-c-not-working-in-flash-playerswf-file-when-browser-is-google-chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP asked question in Adobe forums here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2212890

From staff, this is a **confirmed bug** that "*is fixed*" and "*should be available in the next release build.*"